# Hold the 'Build' process in CircleCI

Tags: build, circleci

Trying to Pause the Auto Build for the approval in circleci. Any suggestions would be greatly aprreciated.

```
workflows:
  build-and-deploy:
    jobs:
      - manual_approval:
            type: approval
            requires:
              - build-kevin_testing
            filters:
              branches:
                only: kevin_testing
      - build-kevin_testing:
          requires:
            - manual_approval
          filters:
            branches:
              only: kevin_testing
          context:
            - circleci-aws-creds
```

I am getting the following error.
" At least one job in the workflow must have no dependencies.
The following jobs are unreachable: build-kevin_testing, manual_approval"

Answer (score 0):

You have a kind of "jobs dependency loop". The `manual_approval` job requires the `build-kevin_testing` job, which itself requires the `manual_approval` job.

That mutual dependency is what's causing the error you're seeing.

There should be no dependency (`requires`) in the definition of the `manual_approval` job:

```
- manual_approval:
    type: approval
    filters:
      branches:
        only: kevin_testing
```